# creating scope methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm playing around with the Active Record Reputation gem https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/wiki/Scope-Reputations.  In my application, I created a reputation system whereby a User gets reputation points for every vote he receives for an answer, and then additional points if he receives the best answer (that code isn't shown). In the `User.rb` model, i calculate a 'karma' reputation (see below) which just sums the total of the two kinds of points he's received.

```
has_reputation :karma,
    :source => [
      { :reputation => :total_vote_points },
      { :reputation => :total_best_points }
    ]

  has_reputation :total_vote_points,
    :source => {reputation: :votes, of: :answers}

  has_reputation :total_best_points, 
    :source => {reputation: :best, of: :answers}
```

The total_vote_points reputation will create a table record like this, with the target_id:8 being the user's id

```
#<ReputationSystem::Reputation id: 24, reputation_name: "total_vote_points", value: 1.0, aggregated_by: "sum", target_id: 8, target_type: "User", active: true, created_at: "2013-03-25 06:07:28", updated_at: "2013-03-25 06:07:28">
```

the karam reputation will create a table record like this

```
#<ReputationSystem::Reputation id: 28, reputation_name: "karma", value: 11.0, aggregated_by: "sum", target_id: 7, target_type: "User", active: true, created_at: "2013-03-25 06:07:35", updated_at: "2013-03-25 06:07:35">
```

Moving on, the gem docs say that scopes can be added to reputation, but don't go into a lot of detail. It gives this example

```
has_reputation :name,
    ...
    :scopes => [:scope1, :scope2, ...]
```

Using my above code, I'm guessing it would look like this if I wanted to check karma points for 'thisWeek' and 'allTime'

```
  has_reputation :karma,
    :source => [
      { :reputation => :total_vote_points },
      { :reputation => :total_best_points }
    ], 
    :scopes => [:thisWeek, :allTime]
```

I'm wondering how I would write the :thisWeek (karma points earned this week) and :allTime (karma points with no restrictions) scope methods.

Knowing that one reputation table record for 'karma' looks like this

```
 #<ReputationSystem::Reputation id: 28, reputation_name: "karma", value: 11.0, aggregated_by: "sum", target_id: 7, target_type: "User", active: true, created_at: "2013-03-25 06:07:35", updated_at: "2013-03-25 06:07:35">
```

Can you suggest how I write the desired scope methods?